# Golang MongoDB Update Query Using Operator IN

Tags: mysql, mongodb, go

Achievement that I want got is query like this in MySQL

```
UPDATE FROM inbox
SET unread = unread + 1
WHERE
projectID = ? AND
userID IN ("A", "B, "C")
```

Is MongoDB have query `IN` like that in MySQL?

I have tried this in Go using `https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver`

```
_, err = m.db.Collection("inbox_counter").UpdateMany(ctx, bson.M{
     "userID":    bson.D{{"$in", userIDs}},
     "projectID": e[0].ProjectID,
}, bson.D{
     {"$inc", bson.D{{"unread", 1}}},
}, options.Update().SetUpsert(true))
```

But it have no effect to my collections

Comment: How does `userIDs` look like?

Comment: @thammada.ts `userIDs` is `[]string` it is array of user id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bson.M{"$in": userIDs}` instead of `bson.D{{"$in", userIDs}}` in filter and
for update use `bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"unread": 1}}` instead `bson.D{{"$inc", bson.D{{"unread", 1}}}}`

```
_, err = m.db.Collection("inbox_counter").UpdateMany(ctx, bson.M{
     "userID":    bson.M{"$in": userIDs},
     "projectID": e[0].ProjectID,
},bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"unread": 1}}, options.Update().SetUpsert(true))
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but my friend said that you can use `$in` for `Find` method only. For now I'm using `BulkWrite` and define `UpdateOne` before as `[]*mongo.Model`. Is there different performance with your code?